# nullable planning variable corrupts score

Tags: optaplanner

I have a  planning problem that assigns some intervals to a shift but some intervals could not be assigned to a shift and so the planning variable is `nullable`. But the problem is, using `FULL_ASSERT` it says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UndoMove corruption: the beforeMoveScore (-20hard/0medium/-1343soft) is not the undoScore (-15hard/0medium/-1343soft) which is the uncorruptedScore (-15hard/0medium/-1343soft) of the workingSolution.
  1) Enable EnvironmentMode FULL_ASSERT (if you haven't already) to fail-faster in case there's a score corruption.
  2) Check the Move.createUndoMove(...) method of the moveClass (class org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMove). The move (14[19:00-19:15] {null -> com.kairos.shiftplanning.domain.ShiftRequestPhase@af44779}) might have a corrupted undoMove (Undo(14[19:00-19:15] {null -> com.kairos.shiftplanning.domain.ShiftRequestPhase@af44779})).
  3) Check your custom VariableListeners (if you have any) for shadow variables that are used by the score constraints with a different score weight between the beforeMoveScore (-20hard/0medium/-1343soft) and the undoScore (-15hard/0medium/-1343soft).
```

In above `14[19:00-19:15]` is the `toString()` method of my interval entity. What I think is, it makes a move to assign `null->some_value` but it does not make an undoMove that does `some_value->null`. Should I implement my own Move class?

Optaplanner version: 7.3.0.Final

Comment: You shouldn't have to build a custom move for this.
Are you willing to build an isolated reproducer and attach it to a jira? In a perfect world, preferably using [this solution and entity classes](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-core/src/test/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/testdata/domain/nullable)?
We have unit tests with those classes, which - until proven otherwise - show that nullable doesn't cause undo move corruption. There might be an uncovered subcase of course, in which case I 'd want to fix it.

Comment: Well, yes, I've got shadow variables listening on nullable planning variables and I've handled it in a way which will corrupt the score if assigned back to null, which I'd expect. Thanks for the head-ups @GeoffreyDeSmet